# Adventure works DW deployment error: lgin failed

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

When I try to deploy the Adventure Works DW 2008 cube, I get the following error:

```
OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Login failed for user 'SpecialSQLServerServiceAccount'.; 28000; Cannot open database "AdventureWorksDW2008R2" requested by the login. The login failed.; 42000.
```

Basically, I have a this account (SpecialSQLServerServiceAccount) which I created and used when installing SQL Server. This account was then given the least amount of permissions by MSSQLSERVER to run all of the services needed.

But alas, it is not working when I try to deploy my Adventure Works DW 2008. What I want to know is what permissions need to be given to my service account or which roles should I add to it and where can I do this? I need the least amount of permission to get the thing deploying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this in SSMS...

```
USE [AdventureWorksDW]
GO
CREATE USER [SpecialSQLServerServiceAccount] FOR LOGIN [SpecialSQLServerServiceAccount]
GO
USE [AdventureWorksDW]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'SpecialSQLServerServiceAccount'
GO
```

Make sure you have the login created on the server first.